# How to combine sequences in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have the following sequences

```
(def a [1 2 3 4])
(def b [10 20 30 40])
(def c [100 200 300 400])
```

I want to combine the sequences element by element:

```
(...  + a b c)
```

To give me:

```
[111 222 333 444]
```

Is there a standard function available to do so? Or alternatively what is a good idiomatic way to do so?

Comment: The particular act of parallel comprehension in functional programming is usually described as "zipping". Some functional languages have a separate "zip" function that can be used in conjunction with "map" while other languages provide a "zipmap" function (sometimes merely called "map"). Clojure falls into the latter case.

Answer (score 16):

if you use clojure-1.4.0 or above, you can use `mapv`:

```
user> (mapv + [1 2 3 4] [10 20 30 40] [100 200 300 400])
[111 222 333 444]
```

Answer (score 15):

The function you are looking for is [`map`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/map).

```
(map + [1 2 3 4] [10 20 30 40] [100 200 300 400])
;=> (111 222 333 444)
```

Note that `map` returns a lazy sequence, and not a vector as shown in your example. But you can pour the lazy sequence into an empty vector by using the [`into`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/into) function.

```
(into [] (map + [1 2 3 4] [10 20 30 40] [100 200 300 400]))
;=> [111 222 333 444]
```

Also, (for completeness, as it is noted in another answer) in Clojure 1.4.0+ you can use `mapv` (with the same arguments as `map`) in order to obtain a vector result.